# How to ensemble on models trained on 3 different datasets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have 3 different datasets with 3 different classifiers that yield the best predictions for them when tested with cross validation. I am trying to find a way to use one of the available ensemble methods from sklearn to give the best prediction based on these 3 datasets. 
Note: All datasets have same number of samples and have similar labels. Just that the nature of data is different. 
I am a newbie to sklearn and I am stuck here. Any help would be greatly helpful.

Comment: How are you planning to use an ensemble method on different datasets with different independent variables? At least you variables should be the same.

Comment: This is my problem - I have some text. There are 3 different analysis on that text. All analysis helps identify only a specific kind of text. I now need to make a final prediction on the individual analysis results. (the analysis yields features that are similar in shape). I thought I run individual predictions on each models and then have a voting mechanism to get the best final prediction.

Comment: So *for each document* you have 3 different classifications, each based on different features extracted from that text?